# Is it necessary for Client application to import all libraries that are used in a Library

Tags: android, android-library

I have created a library that is using `Volley` library in project.

Now when client add this library in their apps, do they also need to add volley in their `gradle` file, or the `gradle` file that is coming with the library is sufficient enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or the gradle file that is coming with the library is sufficient enough

Your library's `build.gradle` should list all dependencies it needs. And that's sufficient for most cases unless you are distributing your library as [AAR](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents), which does not contain `build.gradle` - in that case your lib's dependencies must be included in the app's.

Comment: That depends on how the library is distributed. If it is distributed in source form, or as an artifact in a repository, you are correct. But if the library is distributed as a bare AAR, the dependency information will not be there, and so the app using the AAR would need to add those dependencies directly.

Comment: oh, I am distributing library as an `AAR` file, so i should mention is documents that client need to add `Volley` or other dependencies in their application gradle file

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes, whats the other option, I can;t distribute it through gradle, Its not an open source library, Its for some selected clients

Comment: Well, actually you can have private repos on both jitpack.io and bintray, however this is not free, so depending on your business model it may be an option. Or just update your README with copy-and-paste list or `compile ...` with all dependencies your lib needs.